# How check if there are more rows to display than datagrid height allows

Tags: wpf, datagrid

How check if there are more rows (rows height) to display than datagrid height allows. Default behaviour is when rows are more than datagrid height scrollbar is displayed. Other behaviour can be set SizeToContent="Height".

I want' to override method or bind to event in which I can decide whether scrollbar is displayed or increase window height. This is best option to pick.

Maybe someone have other solutions how can I handle with this problem.

Comment: Maybe you could only deal with MinHeight / MaxHeight ? Or have your Datagrid within a Grid where you choose wisely the min/max/start width/starWidth of each row... ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist DataGridRow Height is calculated by WPF but when I want to get MinRowHeight it return 0 and for RowHeight it return NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Let me insist on using standard WPF features : If you want to have this behaviour :
 a) DataGrid takes the least possible height.
 b) DataGrid can take up to a given height.
 c) When content does not fit that max length, scrollViewer should activate.

Then setting DataGrid's MaxHeight (and only that) is enough, that's exactly the behaviour you will get.
If it is not the behaviour you see, check the Panel in which your DataGrid is inserted, and make sure the issue comes from here.
If you are using a StackPanel, switch right-now to a Grid : StackPanel are champions when it comes to induce strange measure/arrange bugs.